# Помогите разобрать с кодом отправки с формы с ajax на php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, css3, веб-программирование

Вот код 
Нужно: чтобы переменные с формы с помощью ajax "Переходили" в php там обрабатывались, если что-то не так то выдавали ошибку прям в реальном времени( без перенаправлений куда либо), а если все хорошо, то переправить на страницу спасибо за заказ 
Подскажите пожалуйста, буду ооочень благодарен :)

````
<form id="form162657483" name="form162657483" role="form" 
method='POST' data-formactiontype="0" data-inputbox=".t-input-group" class="t-form js-form-proccess t-form_inputs-total_2 "
    data-success-callback="t718_onSuccess">
            <!-- NO ONE SERVICES CONNECTED -->
            <div class="js-successbox t-form__successbox t-text t-text_md" style="display:none;">
            </div>
            <div class="t-form__inputsbox">
                    <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_nm" data-input-lid="1496238250184">
                            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no"
                            field="li_title__1496238250184" style="font-weight:400;">
                                    Ваше имя
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-input-block">
<input id="12345678" type="text" name="name" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " required 
pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]{2,}"  title="Имя может содежжать только русские буквы и больше 2"
placeholder="Ваше имя" data-tilda-req="1" data-tilda-rule="name" style="border:2px solid #4a4a4a;" >
                                    <div class="t-input-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="font-size: 1.2em; float:left; color: red; width:100%; text-align: right;" id="massageShow1"></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-input-group t-input-group_ph" data-input-lid="1496238259342">
                            <div class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" data-redactor-toolbar="no"
                            field="li_title__1496238259342" style="font-weight:400;">
                                    Ваш телефон
                            </div>
                            <div class="t-input-block">
                                    <input type="tel" id="123456789" name="phone" class="t-input js-tilda-rule " required 
                                    placeholder="7 (999)-999-99-99" data-tilda-req="1" data-tilda-rule="phone"
                                    style=" border:2px solid #4a4a4a; " onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/\D/, '')">
                                    <div class="t-input-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="font-size: 1.2em; float:left; color: red; width:100%; text-align: right;" id="massageShow2"></div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                            <div id="result_form" style="color: red; "></div>
                    <div class="t-form__submit">
                            <button id="btn" type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#000000;background-color:#ffd014;border-radius:30px; -moz-border-radius:30px; -webkit-border-radius:30px;">
                                    Оставить данные
                            </button>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </form>
javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
              $('#massageShow1').hide();
             $('#massageShow2').hide();
            // получение данных из полей
            var name = $('#12345678').serialize();
            var phone = $('#123456789').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                // метод отправки 
                type: "POST",
                // путь до скрипта-обработчика
                url: "call6.php",
                // какие данные будут переданы
                data: name, phone,
                // тип передачи данных
                dataType: "json",
                // действие, при ответе с сервера
                success: function(data){
                    // в случае, когда пришло success. Отработало без ошибок
                    if(data.result == 'success'){   
                       alert('форма корректно заполнена');
                    // в случае ошибок в форме
                    }else{
                        // перебираем массив с ошибками
                        for(var massageShow2 in data.text_error){
                          /*   // выводим текст ошибок 
                            $('#'+errorField+'_error').html(data.text_error[errorField]);
                            // показываем текст ошибок
                            $('#'+errorField+'_error').show();
                            // обводим инпуты красным цветом
                            $('#'+errorField).addClass('error_input'); 
                                */ 
                               $('#'+ massageShow2).html(data.text_error[massageShow2]);
                                $('#'+ massageShow2).show();                 
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            // останавливаем сабмит, чтоб не перезагружалась страница
            return false;
        });
    });
php
<?php 
 function validate_russian_phone_number($tel)
    {
    $tel = trim((string)$tel);
    if (!$tel) return false;
    $tel = preg_replace('#[^0-9+]+#uis', '', $tel);
    if (!preg_match('#^(?:\\+?7|8|)(.*?)$#uis', $tel, $m)) return false;
    $tel = '+7' . preg_replace('#[^0-9]+#uis', '', $m[1]);
    if (!preg_match('#^\\+7[0-9]{10}$#uis', $tel, $m)) return false;
    return $tel;
    }
    $name = strip_tags(htmlentities($_POST['name']));
    $phone = strip_tags(htmlentities($_POST['phone']));
    $name = trim($name); 
    $phone = trim($phone); 
    $errors = array(); 
//Проверка на существования
    if( $name == "" || $phone == "" || !isset($name) || !isset($phone)){

        $errors[$pust] = "Пустое значение переменых";

    }
    else if ( $name == $phone){
        $errors[$ravn] = "Они не могут быть равны!!!";
    }

    if ( validate_russian_phone_number($phone) == false ){ 

        $errors = "Валидация Вашего номера не прошла. Повторите попытку"; 
        $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. ' ';  
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. ' ';
        $D =  fopen('data_rom_ero.txt', 'at'); 
        fwrite($D, " ".$useragent. "\n");
        fwrite($D, " ".$ip. "\n");
        fwrite($D, " ".$name. "\n");
          fwrite($D, " ".$phone. "\n");
        fclose($D);
        $errors[$val] = "Они не могут быть равны!!!";
    }
    else { 
        $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. ' ';  
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. ' ';
        $D =  fopen('data_rom_valid.txt', 'at'); 
        fwrite($D, " ".$useragent. "\n");
        fwrite($D, " ".$ip. "\n");
        fwrite($D, " ".$name. "\n");
          fwrite($D, " ".$phone. "\n");
        fclose($D);

        $email = "mail1@yandex.ru, mail2@inbox.ru"; // E-mail куда отправлять заявки.
        $tema = "Важно! Заявка с Яндекс.Директ Важно!"; 
        $message = "Имя клиента: " .$name."<br>"; 
        $message .= "Телефон клиента: " .validate_russian_phone_number($phone)."<br>"; 
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        mail($email, $tema, $message,$headers);

         // страничка спаибо 
        include_once("Thanky.html"); 
    }

if(empty($errors)){
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
}
else { 
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'text_error' => $errors));
}         
?> 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
        // получение данных из полей
        var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            // метод отправки 
            type: "POST",
            // путь до скрипта-обработчика
            url: "call6.php",
            // какие данные будут переданы
            data: {name:name, phone:phone},
            ...
```